# MethodNotAllowedHttpException?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting this error when i want to delete ?

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('admin.property.features.delete',$feature-

        >id) }}" method="POST">
           <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
           <button class="btn-block btn-link delete-btn admin-delete">Delete</button>
        </form>
```

this is my route:

```
  Route::get('admin/property/features/{id}/delete', ['as' => 'admin.property.features.delete', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminPropertyFeaturesController@destroy']);
```

controller:

```
  public function destroy($feature_id){
      $feature = Feature::findOrFail($feature_id);
        dd($feature);
      $feature->delete();

      return redirect()->back()->withFlashMessage('Property features has been deleted successfully!!');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple error. You are only accepting `GET` request in your route list. And the request you are making from view is `POST`. So that's why it showing method is not allowed.

Change the route to POST and it will work.

```
  Route::post('admin/property/features/{id}/delete', ['as' => 'admin.property.features.delete', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminPropertyFeaturesController@destroy']);
```

Edit:

Use `any` to accept any kind of the requests.

```
 Route::any('admin/property/features/{id}/delete', ['as' => 'admin.property.features.delete', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminPropertyFeaturesController@destroy']);
```

Comment: im getting same error its just now for POST at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205

Comment: Can you please go to network tab in chrome and see whether the request is going to the correct route as expected.

Comment: Are you getting $feature while dd?

Comment: can you please try `any` instead of `post` in the route?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132408/discussion-between-arun-code-and-none).